# Невозможность правильно установить значение letter-space в Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой установки дробного значения стилю "letter-spacing" в Safari.
[image: Пример]

Как можно сделатб так что бы устанавливалось верное значение для letter-spacing?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
$("iframe').contents()find("#wrpr_1450105846725").css.letterSpacing = "15px";
```